# Datastructure to map Class objects to values while considering superclasses?

Tags: java

Is there a map like data structure that uses Java Class objects as keys but uses fallback to superclasses if no mapping is found? Let me give a short example:

```
ClassMap<Integer> map = new ClassMap<Integer>();
map.put(Object.class, 1);
map.put(Number.class, 2);

assertEquals(1, map.get(String.class));
assertEquals(2, map.get(Number.class));
assertEquals(2, map.get(Double.class));
```

I know that I could do the fallback manually, e.g.

```
WeakHashMap<Class<?>, Integer> map = // snip

Class<?> cls = Double.class;
Integer i;
do {
  i = map.get(cls);
  cls = cls.getSuperclass();
} while (i == null && cls != null);
```

Still I'm interested in existing or alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any other data structure that would do a reasonable job. You probably will have to code this yourself. The approach you've chosen will perform very well — O(n), where n is the average inheritance depth of the classes you're going to use as keys. N will be constant (and likely very small) for any reasonable class hierarchy. It's pretty unlikely that any other data structure will do better, or be any easier to use.

IMO the more interesting question is how to organise the code you're going to write yourself. One possibility is folding it up as a custom Map implementation:

```
public class ClassMap<V> extends HashMap<Class<?>, V> {
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        //use the logic you mentioned in your question here, with super.get(key)
    }
}
```

then it's at least well contained.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. I've went for a [similar solution](https://github.com/molindo/molindo-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/at/molindo/utils/collections/ClassMap.java) (using a WeakHashMap and an extra method instead of get(..)). Anyway, I'll leave the question as unanswered for the time being, maybe somebody comes up with something smarter.

Comment: Cool. BTW, seeing as you've got an extra method instead of get, have you considered having ClassMap contain a map, but not implement Map itself? ClassMap has some effects (get returning values for keys that don't pass containsKey or appear in the keyset, for example) that while technically not violating the contract for Map, probably aren't what people would expect.

Comment: Why should get return values for keys that don't pass containsKey or appear in the keyset? That's exactly why I've chosen to go for an extra method instead of breaking the contract of get. Am I missing something here??

Comment: No, you're not missing anything — I think we agree. If get() returned values for keys that didn't pass containsKey, it would be a very unusual Map implementation. I guess I was suggesting that for that reason maybe ClassMap shouldn't actually implement Map (or extend WeakHashMap) at all.

Comment: +1.  Don't implement `Map` at all, just provide most of the same methods; you won't be able to do this while satisfying the `Map` contract.